# No image after import Sketchfab to Blender

Tags: import

After importing my file from Sketchfab into Blender I don't get a view. I tested with other files and then there is no problem. Anybody any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Select 'Item' from the right sidebar. What scale, size and location is shown? It looks as if your object is very small. Try scaling it up with the 'S' key.

Comment: Thnx for the tip but even when I scale no image :/

Comment: I think we'd need to see the Blend file in that case. You can upload it to https://pasteall.org/blend/. Don't forget to put the link to it in a comment or in your original question here.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/728e3f0045db4f529dd08310e1d88474

Thank you for checking! :)

Comment: Well I finally managed to find your model in Blender. It actually imported as a very large size (615 x 686 x 298 Meters which is a bit big for a shirt!) and way off centre. I'm not familiar with importing from Sketchfab, but I suggest reading right through the docs [here](https://github.com/sketchfab/blender-plugin/blob/master/README.md) and see if that gives you any clues. Good luck!